# Dualisable object with respect to substitution product

Tags: ct.category-theory

The functor category $[{\sf Fin},{\sf Set}]$ has a monoidal structure given by
$$
F\diamond G := \text{Lan}_J F \circ G
$$
where $J : {\sf Fin} \to {\sf Set}$ is the embedding of the category of finite sets and functions in all sets and functions.

What are the dualisable objects of $[{\sf Fin},{\sf Set}]$ with respect to $\diamond$?

It seems to me that the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $F : {\sf Fin} \to {\sf Set}$ is dualisable with dual $F^\lor$;
2. $\text{Lan}_JF : {\sf Set} \to {\sf Set}$ preserves all small colimits.

If 2. is true indeed, $\text{Lan}_JF$ is a left adjoint, say with right adjoint $R$; now, $F^\lor\cong R\circ J : {\sf Fin} \to {\sf Set}$ is the dual of $F$. But now, it seems to me that $\text{Lan}_JF$ acts as $E\times A$, where $E=F1$. So: $F$ is dualisable if and only if it is the product for $F1$, and its dual is the functor $n\mapsto {\sf Set}(F1,n)$.

Is this all correct?

Comment: This is monoidally equivalent to the category of finitely accessible endofunctors on $\textbf{Set}$ with composition, yes? Duals = adjoints in a category of endofunctors, so, a functor $F : \textbf{Fin} \to \textbf{Set}$ has a right dual wrt $\diamond$ if and only if $\operatorname{Lan} F : \textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Set}$ has a right adjoint _that preserves filtered colimits_. This amounts to requiring that $F X \cong X \times F 1$ with $F 1$ finite.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot that $R$ must be accessible; I agree. Happy holidays!

Comment: Do you know if this has been mentioned or worked out somewhere already?

Comment: The equivalence of functor categories is definitely in the literature – at least the object part of the equivalence is Theorem 2.26 in [LPAC]. The fact that it is a monoidal equivalence, I haven't seen in the literature, but perhaps it is mentioned in connection with Lawvere theories. The characterisation of functors with accessible right adjoints is Theorem 2.26 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5227).

Comment: Sure, sure; I wanted to know whether this characterisation of dualisable objects has already been written up or used by someone

Comment: Then I don't know.